# Error using data factory for copyactivity from cosmos db as source

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

Why do I keep getting this error while using cosmos DB as source in copy activity in data factory v2?

```
[6/26/2018 4:59:37 AM]   "errorCode": "2200",
[6/26/2018 4:59:37 AM]   "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorFormatIsRequired,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Format setting is required for file based store(s) in this scenario.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
[6/26/2018 4:59:37 AM]   "failureType": "UserError",
[6/26/2018 4:59:37 AM]   "target": "CopyFromCosmosDB"
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you need specify format for your sink dataset. If you want to copy it as json or csv or other format. You need specify the format explicitly. You could use ADF V2 UI to author you pipeline.

Comment: Yes I was missing this. Working now!